# Nativescript using _resetRootView

Tags: nativescript

I have a question about `_resetRootView` in Nativescript .. I have a root frame `app-root` that pointing to a dispatcher, the rule of dispatcher is to verify the login, if the user it not logged yet I do `NAVIGATION` with `page.frame.navigate()` if the user is looged in I do `application._resetRootView('app-main-page')` the `app-main-page` is a root with `BottomNavigation`.

I don't have a issue .. but I need confirmation about the concept for more stability :-)

Thanks

Comment: yes, _resetRootView is a good solution. we're using it in production. 
And when the user logs out, just reset the root view back to the login page.

Comment: Thanks Shiva, one more question please .. I just upgraded my NS to 6.3 and now I have an issue with `android` when in my dispatcher I check if the user is logged in, if is true I use `_resetRootView` to `app-main-page` which contient the `BottomNavigation` as root "with out page in it" .. but when I click to a button to navigate, the `page.frame` return `undefined` !

If I do the flowing it work as expected:
- put page into BottomNavigation : 
```xml
<Page>
<BottomNavigation>...</BottomNavigation>
</Page>
```

- Or putting `app-main-page` on app.run` work also

any suggestion ?

Comment: I think both might work, as long you have Frame you can navigate further.

Comment: On android when trying to get `page.frame` it return `null` until change the `tab` and return it work !